# how to create a vertical menu in html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a vertical menu in html/css. i have 5 options to choose from, each should have a height of 20% of the screen. I tried setting the height with height:20% but It had no effect, for some reason setting the width does have an effect. i tried specifying the height in pixels and it worked but for some reason it doesn't work in percentages.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul.menu{
    height:100%;        
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li.menu{

    height: 20%;
        display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: Setting height in percentage can only work if the parent element has a height set as well.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please...

Comment: And the parent's parent? If the parent is 90% but _its_ parent doesn't have a height, the 90% won't do anything. You've got to have some ancestor with an absolute height set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**height:100%** means 100% of the parent height. Since you haven't given height to parent of ul i.e body the code will not work. You need to add the following css

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```